# PHP identify duplicate words in a text string against a list of words

Tags: php, function

I have a list of authors' family names - about 150 names, like: Smith, Jackson, Peters, etc.

I also have a long article (string of text), which mentions the family names of three of the 150 authors that are on the list, but one of these three authors family names is mentioned twice (it is duplicate in the article's text). So this is the main author.

I need a php function/s to compare the list of authors' family names against the text of the article in order to identify which author's family name is mentioned twice and output this author's family name as a variable in order to use it another function.

I searched I lot and most similar topics gravitate towards *preg_match* but could not find this exact use case being solved.

Comment: You could loop through the list, and `strpos()` it against the text. If it hits, `strpos()` again with an offset - if that hits there's two or more instances of the name in the text. Maybe store the final outcome in post meta. In any scenario, this appears to be a question about PHP rather than WordPress, and as such is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use [preg_match_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all) to count the family name occurences of a text. I use the 'i' modifier to search case insensitive.

```
$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Smith consectetur adipiscing elit.
     Johnson Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris
     Smith Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra Smith nec consectetur 
     ante hendrerit.
     Smith Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas 
     mattis sit amet vitae augue.
     Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta Johnson lorem lacinia 
     consectetur.
     Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor.';

$familyNames = ['Smith', 'Johnson', 'Lorem'];
```

Go through all names and match for each family name and count them. Sort by the most found looks like

```
Array
(
    [Smith] => 4
    [Johnson] => 2
    [Lorem] => 2
)
```

and return the topmost which is

```
Smith
```

### Example code

```
$getAuthor = function($text, $familyNames) {
    $scores = [];
    foreach($familyNames as $familyName) {
        $scores[$familyName] = preg_match_all("/$familyName/i", $text);
    }
    arsort($scores);

    return key($scores);
};

echo $getAuthor($text, $familyNames);
```